# Wordpress Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, php7, php5

me gustaria recuperar los post de una categoria de un custom post type. Estoy usando este codigo:

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'ag-categories',
        );
        $arr_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Y me devuelve este error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: object(WP_Query)#7462 (49)

Me pueden ayudar? Gracias!

Comment: Parece que el código no está ejecutándose en el entorno de Wordpress, pues no está reconociendo a la clase `WP_Query`
. Debes explicar cómo haces para colocar tu código en dicho entorno.

Comment: Estoy usando un shortcode

Comment: Pon el array con comillas dobles a ver qué pasa: `$args = array(
            "post_type" => "ag-categories"
        );` ¿Seguro que `ag-categories` existe?

Comment: Con comillas dobles sigue dando el mismo error. Lo declaro aqui: register_post_type( 'ag-categories', $args );

Comment: Prueba con algo más básico, por el momento comenta la línea donde está `WP_Query` y pon esto: `$query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => 4 ) ); var_dump($query);` Si sigue dando el mismo error, pon el contexto completo de tu código.

Answer (score 0):

Como estás usando una taxonomía personalizada,no puedes usar post-type con el valor del nombre de la categoría. Puedes encontrar información sobre la recuperación de taxonomía personalizada en este comentario en la documentación del desarrollador .

De acuerdo con eso, creo que tus $args deben ser:

Recuerda cambiar las variables $post_type por el nombre de tu custom post type.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => $post_type,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'ag-categories'
        )
    )
);

$posts = get_posts($args);
```